# spring cloud gateway fails to route due to netty issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am relatively new to `spring-cloud-gateway` and I am building up a POC for the same.
I have made a sample gateway app and one microservice app for the same. I have verified that the microservice app is running fine and accessible at `port: 8080`

Both of the apps are running good. Hence I am not sharing the `POMs` here. 
However please see below the code details.

> Gateway

`application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: microserviceFirst
        uri: localhost:8080
        predicates:
        - Path= /first

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

`the springboot app`:

```
package com.ey.springCloudGateway;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCloudGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

> The microservice app

`application.properties`

```
spring.application.name="microserviceFirst"
server.port=8080
```

`springboot file`

```
package com.ey.microserviceFirst;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class MicroserviceFirstApplication {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, Object> home() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        model.put("content", "Hello World");
        return model;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroserviceFirstApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I am trying to access using postman to `localhost:8081/first`. Below is the error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.noChunkedTransfer()Lreactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient;
```

That's about it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a known issue and is fixed, with a release pending

Comment: yeah! Even I have commented there today and got to know.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i to did a investigation and i found that the versions for spring boot (parental and gateway cloud)are differents, then i could see in this page (https://www.javainuse.com/spring/cloud-gateway) the example and this other page (https://blog.csdn.net/h363659487/article/details/102780475) the solution.

I hope to be helpful.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>

    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>

        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```